# Как добавить атрибут только первому элементу меню wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

Есть меню и мне нужно выбрать только первый элемент li и добавить в него атрибут, чтобы получилось вот так:

```
        <ul class="sec-nav_list list">
            <li class="sec-nav__item list-item" ><a href="#" class="open-modal" data-modal="#modal1">About</a></li>
            <li class="sec-nav__item list-item"><a href="https://google.com">Gallery</a></li>
            <li class="sec-nav__item list-item"><a href="https://google.com">Shop</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Как это сделать с помощью WordPress? Я делал вот так, но добавлялось ко всем элементам:

```
    add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4 );
    function filter_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
        if ( $args->theme_location === 'rightmenu' ) {
            $atts['data-modal'] = '#modal1';
        }
    return $atts;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать это можно разными способами, привязываясь к классу `open-modal` или `href="#"`. Вот код, который добавляет `data` к просто первому `li` в меню:

```
function filter_nav_menu_link_attributes( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
    static $modal_added = false;

    if ( 'rightmenu' === $args->theme_location && ! $modal_added ) {
        $atts['data-modal'] = '#modal1';
        $modal_added = true;
    }

    return $atts;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'filter_nav_menu_link_attributes', 10, 4 );
```